# How To Export Apk from Unity 3D Using Android Studio. It Shows Some error Like Android Studio Not Found Even After Installing

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, apk

How To Export Apk from Unity 3D Using Android Studio. It Shows Some error Like Android Studio Not Found Even After Installing.

i tried export option in file menu but it navigating to Local Disk C and ask to select a program

Comment: On Windows Android SDK installation path is often identified by environment variables. Most programs don't update them when running so make sure to log off and on or restart your PC to make sure all programs see the updated environment variables and thus are able to find the SDK/Android Studio.